# mySQL InnoDB tables damaged after clean system restart

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a problem with small (it's Raspberry Pi) mySQL installation.
The point is that it's almost sure the InnoDB system files will be corrupted/damaged after system (Debian Linux like) reboot or halt.

Logs show that InnoDB engine was shotdown properly but mySQL does not start after that because of damaged InnoDB files.

Just to explain, Raspberry Pi is a small computer running Debian like Linux.
File system is SD card based.

Hardware is small but I use it to collect some real world sensors data, it's not so unusual to have dozen of thousands rows in the main table.

I asked the question on the RPi forum but it seems I need some more experienced mySQL people to solve it :)

Comment: You can probably look for innodb recovery. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html It has happened to me in past as I use rpi to log industrial sensor's data and they run almost 24x7 6 days a week. That link didn't help me much. I ended up installing the new mysql setup.

Comment: Have you got better results with new fresh install? My only way to go now is to restore database. Can not repair it ...

Answer (score 0):

I did two things and it appears to have helped:

- made sure the debian-sys-maint user was still there so the server actually shut down:

  ```
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on *.* TO 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost'
  IDENTIFIED BY '[password from /etc/mysql/debian.cnf]'
  WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
  ```
- then, added a `sync` in the */etc/init.d/mysql* script in the `stop` case just before the `;`

I had the problem even after a complete reimage (due to power failure corrupting the filesystem) and it's behaving itself especially with the 'sync'.  (shouldn't need to do that, but hey it helps)